# How to properly add 'Appendices' to the TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, tocloft

I need to add 'Appendices' before Appendix A, Appendix B in the TOC. Below code successfully adds it.

```
\appendix

\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}} 
\chapter*{APPENDICES}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}{APPENDICES}{}{}}

\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}} 

\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section}
\makeatother

\include{appendix_materials}
\include{appendix_project}
```

The output is as follows:

```
APPENDICES
  APPENDIX A
  APPENDIX B
```

However, `\chapter*{APPENDICES}` command adds an **extra page** and this is unwanted outcome. When the command removed output becomes as follows:

```
CHAPTER A
APPENDICES
  APPENDIX B
```

Is there any way to get rid of extra chapter page? Or mainly how to add properly 'Appendices' to the TOC?

By the way Appendix A and Appendix B added as chapter because of styling issues.

My setup:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{tocloft}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[page,titletoc,title]{appendix}` I think

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It did not change the output.

Comment: I think I answered your question but there was no feedback so far from you :-(

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your effort but your answer as stated in the question generates extra page for 'appendices'. I do not want appendices page but only it's entry in the toc. In your answer appendices generates a page numbered 3.

Comment: Just remove the `page` option (as I have explained in my post)

Comment: OK thanks, I have tried your answer in an another empty project and worked. However in my setup still won't work, please check the comment in your answer.

Comment: Well your question solved my problem! I was trying to get rid of repeated "Appendices" entries in the TOC. ``\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}`` accomplished that. I had used ``[toc]`` before.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `appendix` package isn't really used correctly in the 'MWE' by the O.P.

Calling `\usepackage[page,toc,titletoc,title]{appendix}` it is possible to have

- A separate page titled `Appendices` (or `Appendix`, if there's only one appendix chapter or section (option **page**)
- The ToC - entry `Appendices` for the separate Appendix - page (option **toc**
- The word `Appendix` as a title to the chapters or sections in the document body (option **title**)
- The word `Appendix` in the `ToC` as well (option **titletoc**)

However, this requires either the usage of multiple `\addappendixpage` etc. commands or `\begin{appendices}...\end{appendices}`.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[page,toc,titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Foo appendix}
\chapter{Foobar appendix}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what can you suggest when appendix chapters added as an include? When they are added as a different tex file the order in the toc changes. Like `\begin{appendices}
\include{foo}
\include{bar}
\end{appendices}`

Comment: In my case (Spanish), the result of option `toc` appears automatically translated, while the result of option `titletoc` or `page` not. According to documentation, these (both ‽ ) depend on `\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Apéndices}`, which makes no difference :(